# How to enable Intel Display Controller instead of NVIDIA?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, display

I have just installed Ubuntu as a Dual-Boot with windows.
I do a have an NVidea graphisc card and an Intel I5 processor with integrated graphics.

I check which hardware, related to Video is in my computer with the following command:

```
lspci -nn | grep '\[03'
```

The output from this command can be found below:

[image]

My NVidia card is connected over DVI with my monitor and my Integrated Graphics is connected over VGA.

Now, when installing Ubuntu, I only had a screen over my DVI output, VGA output was left empty.

I know that the DVI and VGA output can be used as the same time, because when I boot into Windows, I can change from DVI to VGA and both outputs give me my desktop.

So, how can I enable my Intel VGA controller and disable my NVidia in Ubuntu?
I'm trying this because I want to setup VGAPassthrough.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem.
In my BIOS, I can enable Legacy Support.

If I enable this, the video is displayed over my Integrated Graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers
Here you may have the list of additional drivers - for example drivers of graphic card. Select nouvea and Apply changes.

Edit: Oh, Iam sorry, I readed wrong your post, this wont work

Comment: If this is wrong, please remove it.